# How do I load a dialog defined in the Codenameone UI Designer

Tags: codenameone

I have defined a dialog using the UI Designer. How do I now show it in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you would show any form either via a command to navigate to the dialog within the GUI builder or via `showForm("dialogName", null);`

You can also use

```
Dialog dlg = (Dialog)createContainer(fetchResourceFile(), "dialogName");
```

And then you can just use the `show()` method, show packed, modless or any other instance level (not static) show method.